# Proving the Yoneda Embedding is injective on isomorphism classes of objects

Tags: category-theory

I am working through Tom Leinster's Basic Category Theory and I am trying to prove that if $A, A' \in \mathcal{A}$ and $H_A \cong H_{A'}$, then $A \cong A'$. As $H_A$ and $H_{A'}$ are elements of $[\mathcal{A}^{op}, \mathbf{Set}]$, there exists a natural isomorphism $\alpha : H_A \longrightarrow H_{A'}$ and therefore a collection of isomorphisms $(\alpha_B:H_A(B) \longrightarrow H_{A'}(B))_{B \in \mathcal{A}}$.

My thoughts now are that this means $H_A = \mathcal{A}(A,A) \cong \mathcal{A}(A,A')=H_{A'}$, by $\alpha_A$. Does this imply that $A \cong A'$, as required? I am not sure how to show that this is the case, or whether or not it is actually true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Yoneda's lemma, each morphism $\alpha:H_A\to H_{A'}$ is induced
from a unique morphism $A\to A'$. Apply this to $\alpha $ and $\alpha^{-1}$
and you get inverse morphisms between $A$ to $A'$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however is it possible to do this without Yoneda's Lemma? The question comes before it is introduced in the textbook.

Comment: @JamesLeslie You could prove as much of Yoneda as you need in an *ad hoc* fashion. As you say, you have a bijection $\mathcal{A}(A,A)\cong\mathcal{A}(A,A')$. What does $1_A$ correspond to in this bijection?

Comment: This is the route I was trying. As far as I can see, it is a map from A to A', however I can't deduce which it will be. Does the isomorphism preserve the invertibility of the map?

Comment: @JamesLeslie It will be an isomorphism between $A$ and $A'$ in $\mathcal A$.